# what should be used to create link list in C++, structures or classes

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I want to create a link list in C++.I am confused whether to use classes or structures.Is it possible to use pointer for referencing to the class objects and create linked lists with classes only ?
Also can i use the inbuilt lists of c++ to create a list of objects of classes?

Comment: Classes are (almost) identical to structures in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `std::list`. Then, it doesn't matter what you use. For example:

```
std::list<int> listOfInts;

struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

std::list<Point> listOfPoints;

class Line {
public:
    Point a, b;
};

std::list<Line> listOfLines;
```

Comment: :if i have written using namespace std , shall i write std:: again before using list<> ?

Comment: @jairaj: No, that would not be necessary. Regards

Comment: i used the lists using the above syntax.I delcared a list of objects of an class as a private member of another class and it is showing an error : C++ forbids declaration with no type.

Comment: You need `#include <list>` near the top of the source file. Try [this example](http://ideone.com/zU8V0).

Comment: @jairaj you should avoid `using namespace std`. It is guaranteed to cause you hard to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ `class` and `struct` are basically the same, so in the context of this question, it makes no difference.

You can have pointers to objects:

```
class Foo {};

Foo* = new Foo();
Foo f;
Foo* pf = &f;
```

Concerning the differences between `struct` and `class`, the former has public access and inheritance, the latter has private default access and inheritance:

```
struct Bar : Foo {
  int a;
  void bar() const;
};
```

is the same as

```
struct Bar : public Foo {
 public:
  int a;
  void bar() const;
};
```

and the same as

```
class Bar : public Foo {
 public:
  int a;
  void bar() const;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Difference between structs and classes:

- `struct` defaults to public access and `class` defaults to private access.
- When inheriting from them `struct` defaults to `public` inheritance and `class` defaults to `private` inheritance.

Note that C++ standard library already provides linked list:

- singly-linked list (c++11): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list
- doubly-linked list : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list